# Curvature ratio for paraboloid

Tags: calculus

For a paraboloid of revolution whose meridian is given by

$$ y^2 = 2 a ( x -c),\quad \tan \phi = \frac{dy}{dx} $$

Show that

$$ \frac{R_2}{R_1}= \sin ^2 \phi $$

Where $R_1,R_2$ are principal radii of curvature.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the surface is formed by rotating $y^2 = 2 a ( x -c)$ around $x$-axis. Then th equation of the surface is given by
$$ y^2+z^2=2 a ( x -c). $$
So the parametric form is
$$ x=u,y=\sqrt{2 a (u -c)}\cos v,z=\sqrt{2 a ( x -c)}\sin v. $$
Thus the fist fundamental form is
$$　ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=Edu^2+Fdudv+Gdv^2$$
where $E=(1+\frac{a}{2(u-c)}),F=0,G=2a(u-c). $$
Note that

\begin{eqnarray}
r_u&=&(1,\frac{\sqrt{2a}\cos v}{\sqrt{2a(u-c)}},\frac{\sqrt{2a}\sin v}{\sqrt{2a(u-c)}}),r_v=(0,-\sqrt{2} \sin (v) \sqrt{a (u-c)},\sqrt{2} \cos (v) \sqrt{a(u-c)}),\\
r_u\times r_v&=&(1,\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2\sqrt{u-c}}\cos v,\frac{\sqrt{2a}}{2\sqrt{u-c}}\sin v)\times(0,-\sqrt{2a(u-c)}\sin v,\sqrt{2a(u-v)}\cos v)\\
&=&\left(\{a,-\sqrt{2} \cos (v) \sqrt{a (u-c)},-\sqrt{2} \sin (v) \sqrt{a
   (u-c)}\right),
\end{eqnarray}
and
$$ |r_u\times r_v|=\sqrt{a(2u+a-2c)}.$$
So
$$ n=\frac{r_u\times r_v}{|r_u\times r_v|}=\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a(2u+a-2c)}},-\frac{\sqrt{2(u-c)}}{\sqrt{2u+a-2c}}\cos v,-\frac{\sqrt{2(u-c)}}{\sqrt{2u+a-2c}}\sin v\right). $$
From this, we obtain the second fundamental form
$$ II=Ldu^2+Mdudv+Ndv^2 $$
where
$$ Lu=-r_u\cdot n_u=\frac{a}{2(u-c)},M=-r_u\cdot n_v=0,N=-r_v\cdot n_v=2a(u-c).$$
Since $F=M=0$, the principal radii of curvature 
$$ R_1=\frac{L}{E}=\frac{\sqrt a}{(2u+a-2c)^{3/2}},R_2=\frac{L}{E}=\frac{1}{(2u+a-2c)^{1/2}}$$
and hence
$$\frac{R_1}{R_2}=\frac{a}{2u+a-2c}=\frac{a}{2x+a-2c}. $$
On the other hand,
$$ \tan^2\phi=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=\frac{a^2}{y^2}=\frac{a}{2(x-c)}$$
and hence
$$ \sin^2\phi=\frac{a}{2x+a-2c}. $$
So
$$ \frac{R_1}{R_2}=\sin^2\phi. $$

Comment: Are not $R_1,R_2$ interchanged? when  using subscript 1 for meridional direction?

Comment: @Narasimham, I think so.

Comment: Please change it ( as convention $u$ is for meridian, $v$ for parallels) and we are ready for accept.